# Deprecated: mysql_connect(): notice

Tags: php, mysqli, pdo

Recently I've been getting the error:

`Deprecated: mysql_connect(): The mysql extension is deprecated and will be removed in the future: use mysqli or PDO instead`

We all know what causes the error, however I need to launch an application tomorrow and simply dont have time to change all my queries. I'll only be able to get to it during the week. ***In the mean time I would like to know what would be the best way to hide this specific notice without having to use the @ sign or turning error notices of***

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can disable error reporting using this code:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_DEPRECATED);
```

More information at http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php.

However, please use `MySQLi` in future as `MySQLi` supports prepared statements which a safer way of sending data to `MySQL` and protecting you from SQL injection.

Comment: will accept as soon as 10-mins pass

Comment: Really? Instead of upgrading to something actual you propose to *hide* the deprecated errors?

Comment: @Nordenheim It's stated that *We all know what causes the error, however I need to launch an application tomorrow and simply dont have time to change all my queries. I'll only be able to get to it during the week.*. So, it's a temporary 'fix'.

Comment: @luweiqi yeah okay valid point, I didn't really read the rest of the text after the first line